# Variable in sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, filenames, quoting

I have a file that contains filenames with absolute path.

In the middle of that path, is a variable directory, whenever I hard code the variable part, it works fine, but when I replace it with the variable name, the `sed` part doesn't work.

The `sed` part is to delete the pattern or for this matter, the path.

```
file=`echo $one_file | sed 's:/dir1/dir2/$VAR/last_dir/::'`
```

Comment: Try to replace single quotes with double quotes in your sed expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use single-quotes, aka hard quotes, variable names are not expanded. You would need to use double-quotes, aka soft quotes.

```
sed "s:/dir1/dir2/$var/Last_dir/::"
```

or escape the quotes:

```
sed 's:/dir1/dir2/'"$var"'/Last_dir/::'
```

You would also need to be sure that `$var` does not hold any colon, dot, star, `[`, newline or backslash characters or that, if it does, they are escaped.

Comment: $ s="foo|bar" ; echo foobar | sed 's#.*#'"$s"'#;' works...??

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: Yes, but if there is a `#`, newline etc. you would have trouble.