# sed with line break

Tags: sed, variable

I'm trying encrypt a password and replace the word "notset" with this new encrypted password. The problem is that openssl sometimes creates a string with more than one line, like:

```
Salted__▒ہ▒ >▒▒1▒▒▒E
                     ǣ▒▒▒▒"e=8▒ǉ▒{`(̣▒e
```

So, when I run sed, it fails.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
sed -i 's/PASSWORD=.*/PASSWORD='${P}'/' ${PFILE}
```

And the error I'm receiving is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unterminated `s' command
```

Anyone knows how can I replace the whole string, when it has this line brake?
I tried using this before:

```
P=`echo ${P} | tr '\n' "\\n"`
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable in sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99190/variable-in-sed)

Comment: By keeping `${P}` outside quotes, it undergoes word-splitting, that's why the newline is a problem. Keep it within quotes.

Comment: @muru That's _one_ issue. The other being the actual newline in the password.

Comment: @Kusalananda, somehow openssl is creating a string with brake likes. I'm still not sure why.
Here is the command I'm using:
P=`echo 'mysuperpassword3' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -pass pass:'secret'`

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk You would have less trouble with special characters if you would use base64 encoding using the `-base64` option.

Comment: The output of `openssl enc` may contain nul bytes, so you simply cannot store the binary garbage in a variable. Most shell do not support nul bytes in variables, and even with those that do, they cannot be passed as arguments to other commands. Yours is an XY-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable can **not** contain arbitrary binary values (in most shells).

By creating the value of `P` like this:

```
P=$( echo 'mysuperpassword3' | 
          openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -pass pass:'secret')
```

you are exposed to NUL bytes, newlines, `$var` expansions and many other problems. One possible solution is to store the value in a base64 encoded form:

```
P=$( echo 'mysuperpassword3' | 
          openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -base64 -pass pass:'secret')
```

That would avoid many issues but still: variable expansions should be quoted:

```
sed -i 's/PASSWORD=.*/PASSWORD='"${P}"'/' "${PFILE}"
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem.